# Maven импорты cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю зависимости в .pom, в папке Maven Dependencies соответствующие "баночки" и классы отображаются, а импорт выдает ошибку. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Удалил ВСЕ файлы из .m2/repository, затем обновил. Теперь все работает норм.